# How to make first_name+last_name unique in facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, api, callback

Since username is no longer available in facebook callback url field , im thinking using `first_name+last_name` But i dont know if this is unique in facebook so i can use it as username in my website . If not how can i make it unique ?

thanks .

this what im getting

```
  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,email,gender,picture');
```

Comment: I doubt it, because someone can have the same name.

Comment: @Script47 how can i do it be unique from the fields im getting

Comment: What have your tried?

Answer (score 0):

There is one field that you should user to identify returning users, it is the "id" field. Everything else is not unique. You even ask for it in the API call, it will be in the result.
If you want to auto-create a username, use the `first_name` and `last_name` fields, but let the user change it and check if the username exists already.